# C# .Net 6 Asymmetric encryption - Best way to export and import public and private keys

Tags: c#, .net-core, cryptography, rsa

Which is the best way to export and import `RSAParameters` created in **.Net 6** with:

```
RSAParameters PrivateAndPublicKeys, PublicKeyOnly;

using RSA RsaAlg = RSA.Create();

PrivateAndPublicKeys = RsaAlg.ExportParameters(true);
PublicKeyOnly = RsaAlg.ExportParameters(false);
```

There are some examples online but are very different and way too long *(can't be that for encrypt and decrypt you need 10 lines of code and for export and imports key you need 200 lines)*.

Also some examples use `RSACryptoServiceProvider`, which is the difference between this and my example code? (`RSA`)

Comment: *...Best method to export and import public and private keys...* Depends on the encoding (DER/PEM) and format (PKCS#8, SPKI, for RSA also PKCS#1) of the key. .NET 6 has good (but not gapless) support. Gaps can mostly be closed with C#/BouncyCastle.

Comment: @Topaco actually i'm using [this code](cryptography-with-practical-examples-in-net-core-1mc4) just for understand the basics, but i am still a newbie

Comment: You can export the private key as DER encoded PKCS#8 key with `ExportPkcs8PrivateKey()` and the public key as DER encoded X.509/SPKI key with `ExportSubjectPublicKeyInfo()`. Then both keys can be converted to PEM keys using `PemEncoding` (as of .NET 7 this can be done in one step with with `ExportPkcs8PrivateKeyPem()` and `ExportSubjectPublicKeyInfoPem()`). Both PEM keys can be imported with `ImportFromPem()`.

Comment: See e.g. this executable code online: https://dotnetfiddle.net/AGUIAW

Comment: @Topaco thanks for the example, is what i was looking for. But tell me another thing, why i see so many different methods for import and export? (in `RsaAls.` ...). Last thing: the difference from `RSA` and `RSACryptoServiceProvider`?

Comment: *...why I see so many different methods for import and export...*: because there are many different encodings and formats (partly for historical reasons) that have been supported successively over the .NET versions. The consolidation into fewer methods (where encoding and formats are controlled by parameters) was probably not chosen with backward compatibility in mind (just a guess, ultimately only the developers can answer that).

Comment: *...Last thing: the difference from RSA and RSACryptoServiceProvider...*: This cannot be explained in the context of comments, but you can find many posts on the web about this, e.g. as possible starting point: https://dusted.codes/how-to-use-rsa-in-dotnet-rsacryptoserviceprovider-vs-rsacng-and-good-practise-patterns.